# How to send Up and down arrow key to inactive powerpoint slide show window which is in 'Browsed by an Individual {window)' using autohotkey

Tags: automation, controls, autohotkey

1. I have 5 slides in any random powerpoint file.
2. I go to Slideshow > Set up Slide show > Set show type as 'Browsed by an individual (window)'
3. Now, I want to move back and forth between the slides when I have another application opened, let's say notepad. So, I open a new notepad application. Now, if I press PageUp/PageDown key, my AutoHotKey script should send Up/Down arrow key to the inactive powerpoint slide show to that slides changes.

I've written the following AHK script, but it's not working. Where am I making mistake?

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Notepad.exe

PgUp::
ControlSend, mdiClass1 , {Up}, ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE
return

PgDn::
ControlSend, mdiClass1 , {Down}, ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE
return

#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to operate upon the [control's HWND](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ControlGet.htm#Hwnd):

```
PgUp::
    ControlGet, ControlHwnd, Hwnd,, mdiClass1, ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE
    ; MsgBox, % ControlHwnd
    ControlSend,, {Up}, ahk_id %ControlHwnd% 
return
```

Use Window Spy to get the right name of the control.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Unfortunately it's still not working.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `#IfWinActive ahk_exe Notepad.exe` and powerpoint is the active window?

Comment: Yes, it works. I reassigned the key to Home (because PgUp anyway will do slide up)

Comment: Then I don't see another solution as to first activate the powerpoint window, send the key and re-activate Notepad afterwards.

Comment: And if `PgUp` is the right hotkey, you have to use `ControlSend, mdiClass1 , {PgUp}, ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE` or `ControlSend,, {PgUp}, ahk_id %ControlHwnd%` in my code.

Comment: In fact, both Pgup and Up arrow does the same thing. So, I think the problem is somewhere else. I tried by uncommenting the msgbox, it returns a blank message. Something to do with that?

Comment: Use Window Spy to get the right name of the control. On my system is `paneClassDC1` and the above code is working.

Comment: Now, the below code works when PPT is the active window, but when ppt is an inactive window, then it doesn't work!


Home:: 

ControlGet, ControlHwnd, Hwnd,, mdiClass1, ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE

 ;MsgBox, % ControlHwnd

ControlSend,, {Up}, ahk_id %ControlHwnd% 

return

Comment: What ist the version of your MS Office?

Comment: Office 365, windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Try to [run the script as administrator](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs).

Comment: still fails :-(

Comment: Try replacing `ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE` by its `ahk_class` or its title. Maybe `POWERPNT.EXE` has more than one windows in Office 365. And try the code in a standalone script (Use only the above code in the script and close all other scripts that may interfere). It works for me in Office 2010.